# How to write a recursive loop for comma separated nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, xslt-1.0

I am stumped on how to write a recursive loops for the below. Tried comma separating but looks like loop will only work. Any solutions, ideas would be helpful? thanks I am using XML version 1. below is just an example.

My XML source:

```
<Groceries>
    <fruit>Apple,Banana,Peach,Lemon</fruit>
</Groceries>
```

I am looking for an XSLT to get the output below.
So my desired XML output should look like:

```
<Foods>
      <Food raw="Lemon" cat="Fruit" val="Lemon"/>
      <Food raw="Apple" cat="Fruit" val="Apple"/>
      <Food raw="Peach" cat="Fruit" val="Peach"/>
      <Food raw="Banana" cat="Fruit" val="Banana"/>
</Foods>
```

My attempt to create an XSLT solution was:

```
<xsl:element name="Fruit">
  <xsl:attribute name="raw">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(fruit,',')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="cat">Fruit</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="val">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(fruit,',')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
<xsl:element name="Fruit">
  <xsl:attribute name="raw">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(fruit,',')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="cat">Fruit</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="val">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring- after(fruit,',')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should add your attempted solution.

Comment: **1.** Where do the values `Dinner` and `Car` come from? -- **2.** Please post the full and exact expected output; surely you do not need a "recursive loop" to extract only the first value of a comma-separated list? -- **3.** Please state which XSLT processor will you be using.

Comment: version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

Comment: You haven't answered any of my questions.

Comment: I see your point. I'll clarify in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT-1.0 with a recursive template achieves the desired outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/Groceries">
      <Foods>
        <xsl:call-template name="fruit">           <!-- call the recursive template -->
          <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="concat(fruit/text(),',')" />  <!-- add a leading ',' to make the recursive template behave properly -->
        </xsl:call-template>
      </Foods>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="fruit">
      <xsl:param name="txt" />
      <xsl:if test="$txt != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="x" select="normalize-space(substring-before($txt,','))"/>
        <Food raw="{$x}" cat="Fruit" val="{$x}" />  <!-- add 'Food' element with attributes -->
        <xsl:call-template name="fruit">            <!-- call the recursive template with the rest of the comma-separated-string -->
          <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="normalize-space(substring-after($txt,','))" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foods>
    <Food raw="Apple" cat="Fruit" val="Apple"/>
    <Food raw="Banana" cat="Fruit" val="Banana"/>
    <Food raw="Peach" cat="Fruit" val="Peach"/>
    <Food raw="Lemon" cat="Fruit" val="Lemon"/>
</Foods>
```

Answer (score 0):

You build a recursive template by giving a `template` element a name, having it call itself if some condition is met, and invoking it on content using a `call-template` element. Your attempt isn't much of an attempt at all since it doesn't contain any `template` or `call-template` elements and isn't a valid XSLT stylesheet.

This code will recursively produce the described output including the seemingly-random order of output elements described.

```
<transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output media-type="application/xml"/>
    <template name="parse.CSV.string">
        <param name="CSV.string.element"/>
        <param name="CSV.string" select="string($CSV.string.element/child::text())"/>
        <param name="required.item.string" select="string($CSV.string.element/child::text())"/>
        <variable name="item.string">
            <choose>
                <when test="contains($CSV.string, ',')">
                    <value-of select="substring-before($CSV.string, ',')"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <value-of select="$CSV.string"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choose>
        </variable>
        <choose>
            <when test="$item.string = $required.item.string">
                <element name="Food">
                    <attribute name="raw">
                        <value-of select="$item.string"/>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute name="cat">Fruit</attribute>
                    <attribute name="val">
                        <value-of select="$item.string"/>
                    </attribute>
                </element>
            </when>
            <when test="contains($CSV.string, ',')">
                <call-template name="parse.CSV.string">
                    <with-param name="CSV.string.element" select="$CSV.string.element"/>
                    <with-param name="CSV.string" select="substring-after($CSV.string, ',')"/>
                    <with-param name="required.item.string" select="$required.item.string"/>
                </call-template>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </template>
    <template match="/child::Groceries">
        <element name="Foods">
            <call-template name="parse.CSV.string">
                <with-param name="CSV.string.element" select="child::fruit"/>
                <with-param name="required.item.string" select="'Lemon'"/>
            </call-template>
            <call-template name="parse.CSV.string">
                <with-param name="CSV.string.element" select="child::fruit"/>
                <with-param name="required.item.string" select="'Apple'"/>
            </call-template>
            <call-template name="parse.CSV.string">
                <with-param name="CSV.string.element" select="child::fruit"/>
                <with-param name="required.item.string" select="'Peach'"/>
            </call-template>
            <call-template name="parse.CSV.string">
                <with-param name="CSV.string.element" select="child::fruit"/>
                <with-param name="required.item.string" select="'Banana'"/>
            </call-template>
        </element>
    </template>
</transform>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and everything is an attempt in some way.